# How to set the elements selected in an autocomplete field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have users pick genres from an autocomplete field. This field is in the edit view of the profile, so I have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :genres` in the Profile model. Also, Genre and Profile have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association with one another. My question is how do you take the genres that the user picks and set them for that user's profile? What kind of controller code would I need? Would the code go in the profiles or genres controller?

I'm using this for autocomplete: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ I've already prepopulated the genres table and hooked up the script to the text field. Right now when a user types, the autocomplete successfully displays suggestions. Now I want to update the database with the selected genres. This database is a join table between genres and profiles. How and where do I do this?

To sum up, I want to save the association between the profile id and the ids of the genres selected into the join table when I click the button in the profile edit view. Right now I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in ProfilesController#update

unknown attribute: genre
Rails.root: /rubyprograms/dreamstill

app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:18:in `update'
app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:17:in `update'
```

Here's my profile edit view:

```
<%= form_for(:profile, @profile, :url => {:controller => "profiles", :action => "update"}, :html => { :multipart => true, :method => :put }) do |f| %>
...
<%= f.fields_for :genre do |g| %>
 <div class="field">
      <%= g.label :name, "Genres" %><br />
      <%= g.text_field :name, :id => 'genre_field' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
...
<div class="action">
  <%= f.submit :profile, :value => "Update Profile" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What are you using for autocomplete? 
Have a look at this https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Comment: I'm using this for autocomplete: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ I've already prepopulated the database and hooked up the script to the text field. Now I want to update the database with the selected genres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this page http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html

In this page clicking on submit alerts ids of the element, as per my understanding.

The script below in `head` does it

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $(document).ready(function() {  
    $("input[type=button]").click(function () {  
     alert("Would submit: " + $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val());   
    });
   });
</script>
```

This mat help you..
Basically there is an hidden text field which stores ids of the selected elements

Comment: ahh cool... so how do I use this to save the association between the profile id and the ids of the genres selected into the join table?

Comment: name the hidden `input` for autocomplete as `profile[gener_ids]`.. and it should do the trick with simple `profile.save`

Comment: I'm confused... what's the hidden input? Could you provide a code example and tell me in what method of what controller?

Comment: I don't have any experience with `tokenpoint` :(.   I am just answering by looking at http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html.
So can't provide example code, sorry. 
On the example page if you look at the source code you can find a `text_field` with style `display:none`. This field has ids of the elements. e.g For first example `<input type="text" name="blah" id="demo-input" style="display: none;">'
All you need to change `name` of the field from `blah` to `profile[gener_ids]`

Comment: are you getting selected ids in params ?? can you please paste your `params` ?

Comment: yes I am getting selected ids in params. In this example, the id of the genre is 6: `Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update Profile", "profile"=>{"user_attributes"=>{"name"=>"Justin Meltzer", "id"=>"57"}, "genre"=>{"name"=>"6"}`

Comment: Ok so I have to make a hidden field with what name equal to what? Then that hidden field has the ids, and then how do I save those id's to the db?

Comment: Ok just forget it.. you have to change `"genre"=>{"name"=>"6"}` this parameter to be received as `"profile" => {"gener_ids" => [6, 7, 8]}`

Comment: Ohh. you did it... I was busy watching Ind vs Pak Cricket WC semis... please post the final step for community reference... :)

Comment: yeah... the exact answer is here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields Could you change your answer to reflect the code from the railscast please?